# JMETER_HOME environment variable is not defined

Tags: jmeter, environment-variables, jmeter-4.0

I tried to execute `JMeter 4.0` from the command prompt in `Windows 7`.

I got the following error during execution:

> The JMETER_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly This
>   environment variable is needed to run this program

I set `C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin` to `JMETER_HOME` variable, but the problem remains

I can start `JMeter` with its `jar` file.

I use `jdk1.8.0_162` and set `JAVA_HOME` environment variable correctly.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should set `JMETER_HOME` to main JMeter directory as `C:\apache-jmeter-4.0`

Also **don't set** JMeter directory to `JAVA_HOME` variable (should hold Java installation path)

Comment: I set `JAVA_HOME` to Java installation folder.

Comment: I responding to your statement: "I set C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin to JAVA_HOME variable"

Answer (score 4):

Ensure you have installed Java and JMETER Gui works fine first.

Then,

At **User Variables** add `JMETER_HOME` followed by `D:\Jmeter` (Where Jmeter is installed)
Next select **Path** in User variables and add `D:\Jmeter\bin`(Where Jmeter bin path is)

Save and restart cmd.

P.S: This is for Windows solution

Answer (score 2):

- First ensure you've `Java` installed
- Second you need to ensure the working directory of your call is the JMeter installation directory.

Assumption your JMeter installation is located under:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-jmeter-4.0
```

then you need to set this as working directory.

---

As you can read in the jmeter.bat file itself:

> JMETER_HOME - installation directory. Will be guessed from location of jmeter.bat

Answer (score 2):

Asually a wrong JMETER_HOME entry causes this. make sure you have JMETER_HOME pointed to jmeter folder not inside bin directory. For example ,from my local windows i am able to see this thie environment variable

Type : echo %JMETER_HOME%

[image: you should see this in cmd]

Answer (score 1):

This might sound obvious, but I'm getting this error on machines that don't have Java installed. Of course, though a better message might have been nice!

Comment: Please check accepted answer, that solution is working.

Comment: @plaidshirt That is the accepted answer for your specific issue, however the symptoms happen to be the same as when Java isn't installed. It's an obvious thing, but the error might not point you to that.

Answer (score 1):

**Easiest way**: 
just delete the JMETER_HOME environment variable, run jmeter.bat and variable will be added automatically.

Answer (score 1):

For me, setting the Windows environment variable didn't help. Instead it worked when I set the variable at the command line (using the root folder of jmeter).

Like this:

```
SET JMETER_HOME=C:\apache-jmeter-4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

1. ensure java is installed and can check with `java —version`
2. assuming the path jmeter installed is `C:\apache-jmeter-5.3`

   1. add the user variable

      1. press new
      2. add Jmeter variable name as JMETER_HOME
      3. variable value as: C:\apache-jmeter-5.3
   2. add the path

      1. look for *Path* system variable and press edit
      2. edit it to have `C:\apache-jmeter-5.3\bin`
      3. it doesnt have Path(very unlikely), than press new and add variable name as path and value as `C:\apache-jmeter-5.3\bin`
   3. restart cmd and type jmeter should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

One reason for getting this error is to have JMETER_HOME variable defined in the environment variables but pointing to the wrong location. I had this problem due to previous installation.

Answer (score 0):

I got pass this error by commenting out the following in jmeter.bat

if exist "%JMETER_HOME%\bin\jmeter.bat" goto okHome
echo The JMETER_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
echo This environment variable is needed to run this program
goto end

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to set `JMETER_HOME` path explicitly under *user variables*, just add/change under *system variables* under `path` variable as your bin path. If you already have earlier version of JMeter just append with latest version. Path looks like : `C:\XXX\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin`