# Jmeter 4.0 While opening jmeter.bat from command line showing exception JMETER_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly

Tags: jmeter

C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin>jmeter.bat
The JMETER_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program

JMETER_HOME is set correctly in environment variable.

ApacheJMeter.jar is working fine.

Similar issue found in below link but this also not helping me.

[JMETER_HOME environment variable is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48882280/jmeter-home-environment-variable-is-not-defined)

Comment: C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin>java -version
java version "9.0.4"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)

Comment: OS Windows 10 64 bit

Comment: have you tried execute `set JAVA_HOME=C:\apache-jmeter-4.0` before?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set `JMETER_HOME` variable manually, `jmeter.bat` script should detect it automatically.

Just in case you want to override it for any reason make sure you do this carefully and the variable points to your JMeter installation like:

```
set JMETER_HOME=C:\apache-jmeter-4.0 pushd %JMETER_HOME% && jmeter.bat
```

It might also be the case that Windows doesn't have necessary permissions assuming JMeter lives in root of system drive, try [running command prompt as Administrator](https://www.howtogeek.com/194041/how-to-open-the-command-prompt-as-administrator-in-windows-8.1/)

More information:

- [Running JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#running)
- [How to Get Started With JMeter: Part 1 - Installation & Test Plans](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-part-1-installation-test-plans)

Comment: Thanks, running command prompt as Administrator resolved my Issue.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to set JMETER_HOME path explicitly under user variables, just add/change under system variables under path variable as your bin path. If you already have earlier version of JMeter just append with latest version. Path looks like : C:\XXX\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin

Comment: This doesn't resolve the issue. JMETER_HOME environment variable.....bla bla bla still pops up in command line